# Incorrect printed message in tensorflow image classification tutorial due to warning "Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll';...."

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-classification

I am following along an image classification tutorial from tensorflow from the following link:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification.

I have tried following along and when I reach the lines

`image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.jpg')))`

and

`print(image_count)`

and run them on my laptop, the number that is printed is 492 instead of 3670. I have not modified the tutorial code in any way. Additionally, when I run the code, before the number is printed, I receive these two warnings:

```
2020-09-29 09:46:38.508600: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found

2020-09-29 09:46:38.508868: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

I have looked online for solutions to the issue to no avail. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Are you using `GPU` device or `CPU` device to perform above task? If you are using `CPU` device then please ignore above warning. If you are using `GPU`, then there is an issue with your `Tensorflow GPU` installation. I have executed code in Colab and it is working as expected.

Comment: I'm not sure which one I am using, how do I check?

Comment: Can you please run `tensorflow.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` and let me know what it returns?

Comment: Where do I run that? Command prompt?

Comment: Where did you install Tensorflow?

Comment: I installed it from the command prompt using pip

Comment: Then please run above code there, only after `import tensorflow as tf`

Comment: Ok so something really strange is happening, when I try and download tensorflow on pip, it says a bunch of statements with "requirements already satisfied", but when I run the "import tensorflow" statement in IDLE, it gives me an error that says "no module named tensorflow"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222368/discussion-between-tfer2-and-srt).

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? Else let us know the your current status so that we can help you?

Comment: Never got it to work on the old laptop, switched to a new device and it somehow worked perfectly.